# TypeScript: Get type of a property

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get the type of a property in another type.

For example, I have a type `A`, and I need to get the type of `b`.

The only method I could come up with is make a instance of `A` and get `b`'s type.

```js
type A = {
  a: string
  b: number
}
const a: A = null


type B = typeof a.b
```

Comment: `type B = A['b'];` Also please don't post pictures of code.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Thanks, did no I shouldn't post pictures

Comment: BTW, what if I want to show the inferred type IDE gives me, how can I do that in a clear way without an image.

Comment: My IDE lets me select and copy the text inside the tooltips; I usually paste them into comments in the code, like `const a = {b: "hello"};` followed by `/* const a: {
    b: string;
} */`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `typeof`

```
type A = {
    a: string
    b: number
}
const a: A = null

type B = typeof a.b
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the indexed access type. Adapting the typescript example to your example above:

```
type A = {
  a: string
  b: number
}
type B = A["b"];
```

It is no longer necessary to create an instance, which makes this preferable. From the docs at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html.