# How to access inter interface which not export in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the `FileConfig` interface, which includes the `FileProps` interface.

Those interfaces are in `type.ts` file, and they are outside my project (in `node_modules`):

```
interface FileProps {
  type?: string;
  label?: string;
}

export interface FileConfig<
  Props = FileProps & {
    [additionalProperties: string]: any;
  }
> {
  name?: string;
  props?: Props;
}
```

I want to create `foo` function that takes two arguments, one is for `FileProps` and the second for `FileConfig`.

The problem is `FileProps` is not export so I can't able to import from this file.

Is possible with typescript to access `FileProps` from `ConfigProps`?

```
import { FileConfig } from './type';

function foo(props: FileProps, config: FileConfig) {}
```

Something like this? (`FileConfig.FileProps`)Ï

```
import { FileConfig } from './type';

function foo(props: FileConfig.FileProps, config: FileConfig) {}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-g3qfe7?file=foo.ts,type.ts)

Comment: You mean `FileConfig["props"]` (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72408025/3001761)? But why not just take _one_ parameter, the whole `FileConfig`?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve Props from FileConfig, however, there is no way to exclude `[additionalProperties: string]: any;`

```
import { FileConfig } from "./type";

var configType: FileConfig;
type FileProps = typeof configType.props ;

function foo(props: FileProps, config: FileConfig) {
  
}
```